# Unable to click on an angular item with python

Tags: python, css, angularjs

I am searching for a particular item on a page and if I find it, I want to click on it. My code in Python is able to find the containing class but when I try to find the element with angular and click on it, the code just skips over it.

Below is the code with the angular item I am trying to click on:

```
<div class="cta-wrapper" ng-show="!webinarModel.showForm">
            <a class="btn center second" ng-click="controller.registerUserForSelectedDate()">Continue</a>
        </div>
```

I have tried to search for it by css selector, class name and xpath but it just doesn't click. Here are my examples of what I have tried below:

```
form_element.find_element_by_class_name('btn center second').click()
form_element.find_element_by_css_selector("//a[@ng-click='controller.registerUserForSelectedDate()']").click()
form_element.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/section/article/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/a').click()
```

It is wrapped in a try statement but just keeps skipping to the except and moving on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.btn.center.second'))[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true
}));
```

Comment: I am using Pycharm for automated tests. I am unable to just throw this javascript in my test. What do you use to integrate javascript with your Python code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


element = Webdriver(form_element, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Continue")))
element.click()
```

I installed a ton of different libraries but I kept searching and came across this and thankfully it worked! I hope this helps someone else!